# Specify -p option on compiled Perl script

Tags: perl, executable

I am using Strawberry Perl under Windows 10. I have a Perl script that I always call with a -p option.

I would like to compile it to an executable .exe using the *pp* program from *PAR::Packer*. Is it possible to specify that it should execute with a *-p* option?

Either on the command of the compilation *pp* command or on the command line of the resulting executable is run would be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about `PAR::Packer', but perhaps if you give the script a shebang line

```
#! windows/ignores/this -p
...
```

`PAR::Packer` might respect it in the executable file.

If not, you can always* convert a `-p` using script into a regular script like so:

```
perl -MO=Deparse -p myscript-p.pl > myscript-no-p.pl
```

* - unless your script has unusual constructions that `B::Deparse` can't deparse correctly

Comment: I don't know if I was incorrectly using the shebang or not, but the use of Deparse worked for me.

Comment: The Deparse way will change line numbers and may even introduce differences and errors, creating debugging nightmares if you don't keep the generated file.

Answer (score 3):

The `-p` switch has a defined behavior and its documentation shows [equivalent code](https://perldoc.pl/perlrun#-p), so just write your program to work that way to begin with.

```
LINE:
  while (<>) {
      ...             # your program goes here
  } continue {
      print or die "-p destination: $!\n";
  }
```

(If on Perl 5.22 or newer, consider using [<<>>](https://perldoc.pl/perl5220delta#New-double-diamond-operator) instead of `<>`.)